# Deleting a row from an embedded document in mongo engine

Tags: python, mongodb, cherrypy, mongoengine

I have a document called `login_info`. It has two fields:

- name
- password
- Location

`Location` is an embedded document with two fields:

- datetime
- city

There are datas in the embedded document and i want to delete a row from it.
 for eg: i have to delete all the rows with location "Canada". How can i do this in mongo engine ? any help

Comment: There is no row in MongoDB. What do you want to delete ? The full document which contain location.location = 'canada' ? Only the subdocument ? BTW you shouldnt have a field with the same name in a document and in a subdocument, that's best way to have a bug ;)

Comment: yeah i just want to delete the subdocument only. yeah I will change the name 'location' to 'city'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.login_info.update({}, {$pull:{location:{city:"Canada"}}})
```

Ok try this instead

```
db.login_info.update( { "location.city" : { $exists : true } }, { $unset : { "location.city" : "Canada" } }, false, true);
```

This will remove all "rows" where city is "Canada".

Comment: if you need to modify more than one document, add the "multi" modifier.

Comment: the $ sign in both the codes are showing error. its showing lexical error.

Comment: This works fine on mongo shell. The error you are getting is to with  the language you are using, not mongo.

Comment: @jamjam how can i achive this in mongo engine?